# Role of Ament in ROS 2 package creation

Tags: ros, ament

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [Creating Your First ROS2 Package](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package/)  tutorial, the command to create a new Python package is:

```
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python my_package
```

I'm confused by the appearance of `ament` in the above command. Since I am using Dashing, I would not expect to use `ament_tools` or probably anything with `ament` in its name, since ROS 2 is now using `colcon`.

Is this a vestige of earlier releases, or do I have a misconception?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370037/role-of-ament-in-ros-2-package-creation/) by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2021-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems that `ament_tools` is gone and replaced with `colcon` but `ament` is still alive.

---

Originally posted by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) with karma: 130 on 2021-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0